# Solving a 4th order BVP using python

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve a 4th order ODE

- EI*(d4y/dx4) = -k*y

which is a version of an ODE for a foundation on soft soil.

My system of first-order equations is the following

- y1' = y2
- y2' = y3
- y3' = y4
- y4' = -k*y1

and the BCs

- y3(0) = y3(L) = 0
- y4(0) = -F/(EI)
- y4(L) = 0

and my code

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import numpy as np

F = 300 #kN
EI = 20000 #kNm2
D = 1 #m
M_E = 45000 #kN/m2
k = 1.4*M_E/D #kN/m3
L = 10 #m

x = np.linspace(0,L,101)

p = np.array([k,EI,F])

print(p)

def fun(x, y, p):
    k = p[0]
    EI = p[1]
    return np.vstack((y[1],y[2],y[3],-k*y[0]/EI))

def bc(ya, yb, p):
    F = p[2]
    EI = p[1]
    return np.array([ya[2], yb[2], ya[3]+F/EI, yb[3]])


y_a = np.zeros((4, x.size))


from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

res_a = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y_a, p)
```

I get the following error:

#ValueError: 'bc' return is expected to have shape (7,), but actually has (4,).

Could you help me understand what I am doing wrong here and what the error means?

Thanks

Comment: see [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_bvp) you don't have enough boundary conditions to solve this problem

Comment: Don't I need 4 BCs for 4 equations? Theoretically, this should be enough.

Comment: Here x is a 1-D independent variable, y(x) is an N-D vector-valued function and p is a k-D vector of unknown parameters which is to be found along with y(x). For the problem to be determined, there must be n + k boundary conditions, i.e., bc must be an (n + k)-D function.

Comment: What is p exactly? If it is a vector of constants in my problem like stiffness k or force F, then I already know them. Why should they be unknown? Or is this something else?

Comment: again, from the docs: "p: array_like with shape (k,) or None, optional
Initial guess for the unknown parameters. If None (default), it is assumed that the problem doesn’t depend on any parameters."

Comment: Yes, but what is p exactly – in a mathematical sense?

Comment: It is the initial guess for any unknown parameters, since you don't have any, you can just get rid of ```p``` everywhere and it works

Comment: In other solvers, `p` as used in `solve_bvp`, would have to be implemented as additional components of the state vector that have derivative zero. You could add their residuals to their fixed values to the boundary condition. This may give the solver more flexibility to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, after playing around with the code, I managed to make it work. The solution would be:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import numpy as np

F = 100 #kN
D = 1 #m
M_E = 50 #MN/m2
E_cm = 33600 #MN/m2
L = 10 #m
nodes = 40

x = np.linspace(0,L,nodes)

k = 1.4*M_E/D #kN/m3
EI = E_cm*0.25*np.pi*(D*0.5)**4 #kNm2

c =k*D/EI


def fun(x, y):
    return np.vstack((y[1],y[2],y[3],-c*y[0]))

def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[2], yb[2], ya[3]+F/EI, yb[3]])


y_a = np.zeros((4, x.size))


res_a = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y_a)


y = res_a.sol(x)[0]*10**3
theta = res_a.sol(x)[1]*10**3
M = EI*res_a.sol(x)[2]
V = EI*res_a.sol(x)[3]
```

I hope this helps anyone who is struggling with implementing an ODE of orders higher than 2.

Comment: please indicate by text in the answer what you changed to make it work and why that worked. Currently, one must read all the details in both code snippets and compare the two to understand what the issue was.